# Solving ODE numerically, using derivative steps

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Assume I have the ODE $\dot{p}(t) = f(t,p)$, with $p(0) = p_0$ and assume $f(t,p)$ (for simplicity) is only a function of $p$. I want to solve the ODE numerically, using derivative steps, kind of like Euler method. We know that
$$
\dot{p}(t) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{p(t+h)-p(t)}{h}
$$
and when taking a small, but finite $h$, we get that
$$
\dot{p} \approx \frac{p(t+h) - p(t)}{h}
$$
and from this, I can approximate the next step and get
$$
p(t+h) \approx p(t) + h\cdot f(p(t))
$$

Now I want to get a better approximation, and use the fact that
$$
\dot{p}(t) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{p(t+h) - p(t-h)}{2h}
$$
and with small $h$ I get the next step approximation
$$
p(t+h) = p(t-h) + 2h\cdot f(p(t))
$$

My question is, how can I perform the first step, when $t = 0$? Since I only have $p(0) = p_0$, I can't calculate $p(-h)$. Is there an efficient way to approximate this?

Comment: Newton's method?

Answer (score 1):

A simple alternative is to use another method for the first step, $t=t_{1}$. In your case, use the following:
$$
p_{1}=p_{0}+hf(p_{0})
$$
Once you have the values for $p_0$ and $p_{1}$, you can proceed to apply your scheme.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Taylor expansion. Assuming you're trying to solve
$$
p'(t) = f(t, p(t))\\
p(t_0) = a
$$

Let's expand $p(t)$ around $t = t_0$:
$$
p(t) = p(t_0) + (t - t_0) p'(t_0) + \frac{(t-t_0)^2}{2} p''(t_0) + \mathcal O((t-t_0)^3)
$$
Since $p'(t) = f(t, p(t))$ we can substitute $p'(t_0) = f(t_0, p(t_0)) = f(t_0, a)$.

Differentiating the ODE one get
$$
p''(t) = f_t(t, p(t)) + f_p(t, p(t))p'(t)
$$
and again, it could be evaluated at $t=t_0$ using the initial condition
$$
p''(t_0) = f_t(t_0, a) + f_p(t_0, a) f(t_0, a).
$$
This procedure can be continued for derivatives of any order.

The approximation
$$
p(t_1) = p(t_0) = a
$$
would result in first-order method and the
$$
p(t_1) = a + h f(t_0, a)\\
p(t_0) = a
$$
will have the second order, assuming the ODE is also approximated with the second order, which is true for the symmetrical difference you've used.

The second derivative computation I've shoved above is used for higher method orders.